# Server Error in Application. Invalid object name 'dbo.Categories'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am working on a Online Shopping Web Apps using ASP.NET and Entity Framework c#. The problem is that my application runs fine when I test it on my local ASP.NET Development Server, but when I host the website, it gives the following error:

> Server Error in '/samarth' Application.
>       Invalid object name 'dbo.Categories'.
>
> ```
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web 
>
> request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Categories'.
> ```

Is there something wrong with the connection string?

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="CommerceEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data_Access.EDM_Commerce.csdl|res://*/Data_Access.EDM_Commerce.ssdl|res://*/Data_Access.EDM_Commerce.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Commerce.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Got this error:

> The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

Comment: you ask "Is there something wrong with the connection string?" - but you haven't shown it!

Comment: Check [this](http://aspspider.info/samarth/) for demo.

Comment: This is a very explicit error: "Invalid object name 'dbo.Categories'."  Either your permissions are wrong, you are pointing at the wrong DB, and you haven't deployed your target DB correctly.  Fix it.

Comment: I am having trouble dealing with connection string, I guess.

Comment: -1 Voting down does not solve my problem, it even does not help. I also vote down your effort to help and understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` which mean you making connection to database as this exception is returned by databse, most probably your do not have updated database on server. Check if you have `dbo.Categories exists` on database you are connecting. You can read more about connection string **[here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012)**

Comment: I have uploaded the same database to be used on server. dbo.Categories exists.

Comment: Check the connection string if you have right database server and database?

Comment: My Hosting Service Provider say I should make this as my connection string: `"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=YourUserId_DatabaseName"
`

Comment: But if I use these connection strings, the metadata information in the **CommerceEntities** connection string will be lost. please guide.

Comment: Can you access other database object like other tables or stored procedures? You need to make sure that you have dbo.Categories in the database, you may need to ask Service Provider for help

Comment: No, My connection string is wrong, Can you help me with that?

Comment: You can go through and find what suits you, http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

Comment: Can't find anything suitable.